# Prevent loading an assembly in c#

Tags: c#, loading, .net-assembly

I want to prevent an assembly to be loaded from another application. So that it can be loaded from my application only.

Rigth now I'm using `Assambly.LoadFrom` to load the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to validating entry assembly (`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`) somewhere in your 'protected' assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, no. It sounds like you are deploying a dll, but you want to retain sole control over how it is used. That is just an arms race; ultimately if somebody **really, really** wants to (ab)use it, they can. Even if that means disassembling, de-obfuscating, and disarming any preventative code you have added.

The only way to block that: don't give it to them.  Consider using a web-service for some functions. Then they don't have the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) in your assembly and specify your application assembly as a "friend". This will prevent other assemblies of using types provided they are marked as `internal` but will allow your application to still use those types.

From MSDN:

> Ordinarily, types and members with
>   internal scope (in C#) and friend
>   scope (in Visual Basic) are visible
>   only in the assembly in which they are
>   defined. The
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute
>   makes them also visible to the types
>   in a specified assembly.
>
> The attribute is applied at the
>   assembly level. This means that it can
>   be included at the beginning of a
>   source code file, or it can be
>   included in the AssemblyInfo file in a
>   Visual Studio project. You can use the
>   attribute to specify a single assembly
>   that can access the internal types and
>   members of the current assembly. To
>   make the assembly's internal types and
>   members visible to additional
>   assemblies, you must include a
>   separate InternalsVisibleToAttribute
>   attribute for each assembly.

Not that this does not prevent anyone from *loading* your assembly, it just prevents them from *using* the internal types within the assembly (at least not without some major effort, in the end anyone can just disassemble  your code and use it that way).

Comment: and use only internal classes, which may be difficult at some point

Comment: It should be stressed that this only preened very casual abuse.

Comment: @Marc: Agreed - as soon as your code/assembly is in the hands of the user there's no security measure that will hold up forever if someone is willing to put enough effort into breaking it (Schneier would approve)

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop people from using your DLL using technological approach. You can try to make it more difficult but a sufficiently skilled user will be able to modify the assembly so that they can use it.

You could try a legal approach. You can include a clause in your license agreement which disallows people from using your assembly in another application. But it won't stop everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscate it and keep documentation secret. Also include a key as in:
http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c4643

Comment: The SN of an assembly is visible in the assembly. It just mitigates *tampering* of the assembly (e.g. adds "source trust") -- it doesn't control access to the assembly beyond the internal resolution and load checks. I gave a +1, because there are tools (not the SN) to encrypt an assembly and decrypt it on-the-fly/at load and I believe this question could be made better if it explores that path more. However, it's still has the problem: if program X can you can access it, so can program Y -- e.g. it is hacked to inspect how the assembly is being loaded :-)